# operation on a very large raster in terra causes std::bad_alloc

Tags: bigdata, raster, terra

I have a large raster and I do not understand how to process it. My assumption was that I can cut it into tiles, make a vrt and then process the vrt to get the answer. But it is not so (at least not using my code), so I hope to find some guidance here.

My code:

```
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra")
v <- vect(f)
r <- rast(v)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
r2 <- disagg(r, fact = c(4000, 5000)) # make a really big raster

tester <- zonal(r2, v, summary = "range") # calculation that is too big to handle
# this throws Error: std::bad_alloc

filename <- "test_tile/test_.tif"
ff <- makeTiles(r2, 1000, filename) # make it into many small tiles, hopefully to process
vrtfile <- "test_tile/testing.vrt"
vrt_thing <- vrt(ff, vrtfile)

tester <- zonal(vrt_thing, v, summary = "range") 
# this also throws Error:std::bad_alloc
```

In a nutshell, I thought each tile would be processed in the background with that call, one at a time, and the results magically stitched together. That is not how it works, which indicates I have misunderstood something. Any help to find a way to do my zonal calculation much appreciated. (note, this is a reproducible example, not my data... I am not looking for the literal result from this file...). Ultimately I need to perform this calculation many times with many different polygons one one static raster.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are doing since your code does not run.

```
library(terra)
# terra 1.7.72
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package = "terra")
v <- vect(f)
r <- rast(v)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
test <- zonal(r, v, summary = "range")
# Error in .local(x, z, ...) : unused argument (summary = "range")
```

In `terra::zonal` the argument would be "fun" but that does not accept "range".

```
test <- zonal(r, v, fun="range")
# Error: [zonal] Unknown function
test <- zonal(r, v, fun=range)
# Error: [zonal] this 'fun' is not supported. You can use extract instead
```

However, you can do

```
rvmin <- zonal(r, v, fun="min")
rvmax <- zonal(r, v, fun="max")
```

or

```
e <- extract(r, v, fun=range, ID=FALSE)
```

The results are the same

```
head(e)
     lyr.1 lyr.1.1
[1,]     4      25
[2,]    35      47
[3,]    41      63
[4,]    36      36
[5,]    23      34
[6,]    58      60

head(cbind(rvmin, rvmax))
  lyr.1 lyr.1
1     4    25
2    35    47
3    41    63
4    36    36
5    23    34
6    58    60
```

If this does not help you can change assumptions about memory availability with `terraOptions`

Comment: thank you for taking the time to correct that mistake in my code. I have fixed the code, with tester <- zonal(r2, v, fun = "max"), and still encounter std::bad_alloc. I am afraid I do not quite understand the memory availability options very well, perhaps you can indicate which options I should alter to help me process the ginormous raster? My current options are 
memfrac   : 0.6
tolerance : 0.1
verbose   : FALSE
todisk    : FALSE
tempdir   : C:/.../Local/Temp/RtmpeciHgw
datatype  : FLT4S
memmin    : 1
progress  : 3