# Error std::bad_alloc using `terra::extract` on large stack and many points

Tags: r, terra

I'm trying to run a bilinear `terra::extract` of > 2 700 000 point coordinates on a SpatRaster stack with many layers (2880, although each with 100 cells only) and getting "Error: std::bad_alloc", probably because I run out of memory.

I've I thought about processing this sequentially using a `lapply` on a list version of my stack (something like `as.list(stk)`) but it will take ages to process, I think (based on a benchmarking exercise with the first two layers), so I was hoping for another solution.

I can probably split the SpatRaster into sections, but I thought `terra` would do that automagically, but processing by chunks

Here's a reprex:

```
library(terra)
library(data.table)

r <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 11, ext = c(-130.3125, -109.6875, 45.625, 58.125), resolution = c(1.875, 1.25),  crs = "EPSG:4326")
r[] <- runif(n = ncell(r))
stk <- eval(parse(text = paste0("rast(list(", paste(rep("r", 2880), collapse = ", "), "))")))

xyz <- data.table(x = sample(seq(-130.3125, -109.6875, by = 0.0001), size = 2785518, replace = TRUE),
                  y = sample(seq(45.625, 58.1255, by = 0.00001), size = 2785518, replace = TRUE))

tester <- extract(stk, xyz, method = "bilinear") 
# Error: std::bad_alloc
```

I've trying setting `terraOptions(memmax = 0.1, memmin = 0.1)` to see if that increased the number of processing chunks (or triggered it), but it didn't and I get the same error.

```
> mem_info(stk)

------------------------
Memory (GB) 
------------------------
check threshold : 1 (memmin)
available       : 23.98
allowed (60%)   : 14.39
needed (n=1)    : 0
------------------------
proc in memory  : TRUE
nr chunks       : 1
------------------------
> terraOptions(memmax = 0.1, memmin = 0.1)
> mem_info(stk)

------------------------
Memory (GB) 
------------------------
check threshold : 0.1 (memmin)
available       : 0.1 (memmax)
allowed (60%)   : 0.06
needed (n=1)    : 0
------------------------
proc in memory  : TRUE
nr chunks       : 1
------------------------
```

This issue is potentially related to [operation on a very large raster in terra causes std::bad_alloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77965620/operation-on-a-very-large-raster-in-terra-causes-stdbad-alloc?rq=2)  but I couldn't find a solution there

UPDATE:
Following @robert-hijmans 's second suggestion here's a solution that uses `extract(..., bilinear = TRUE)` and avoids extracting the same cell value more than once:

```
library(terra)
library(data.table)

r <- rast(nrow = 10, ncol = 11, ext = c(-130.3125, -109.6875, 45.625, 58.125), resolution = c(1.875, 1.25),  crs = "EPSG:4326")
r[] <- runif(n = ncell(r))
stk <- eval(parse(text = paste0("rast(list(", paste(rep("r", 2880), collapse = ", "), "))")))

xyz <- data.table(x = sample(seq(-130.3125, -109.6875, by = 0.0001), size = 2785518, replace = TRUE),
                  y = sample(seq(45.625, 58.1255, by = 0.00001), size = 2785518, replace = TRUE))

## get raster cell coordinates for the selected points:
point2CellCoords <- data.table(cell = cellFromXY(stk, xyz), xyz)

## now make a vector of unique cell coordinates
uniqueCoords <- data.table(cell = point2CellCoords$cell, xyFromCell(stk, point2CellCoords$cell)) |>
  na.omit() |>
  unique()

## extract for unique locations and bind back to all points.
tester <- extract(stk, uniqueCoords[, .(x, y)], method = "bilinear") |>
  as.data.table()
tester$cell <- uniqueCoords$cell

result <- tester[point2CellCoords, on = "cell"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the extraction in chunks. That is, do not split the rasters, but rather do the extraction for subsets of the points (rows of `xyz`).

For example

```
i <- ceiling(1:nrow(xyz) / 500000)
u <- unique(i)
tester <- lapply(u, extract(stk, xyz[u==i, ], method = "bilinear") )
tester <- do.call(rbind, tester)
```

Since you have 2,700,000 points and only 100 cells you could do the below to avoid memory limitations. With raster `r` and points `p` you could do

```
cells <- cellFromXY(r, p)
v <- values(r)
result <- v[cells, ]
```

But since you do extract with "method=bilinear" that may not apply. In that case it could still be useful to do only extract the values for the unique coordinates, and then merge the results with the original points.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that -- I'll give it a try ASAP. One question, though: why isn't `terra` increasing the number of processing chunks? Did I completely misunderstand that those are and how they are adjusted?

Comment: processing chunks normally refer to raster data. Reading raster data in chunks does not apply here. The raster data is only read for the point locations. The issue is that the size of the output data (2700000 * 2800 =  7.56e+09 values) is too large for a contiguous C++ object on your computer.  Chunking the point data might help.